# Is it better to use spring mvc with hibernate?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jsp, spring-mvc

I am going to develop **small ERP System**. The product has only one major requirement to support multiple databases.

I have planned to use

**Front side:** JSP+JSTL+JQuery [I have good command on that] + I have create my own custom component for re-useability and full control of my component.

**Back-end:** Using hibernate[ORM] framework [due to Cross database] and I have also good knowledge of it.

I am happy with above and feeling confident to build product, soon.
**BUT**

```
My friend made me unhappy ;)
```

My friend suggest me that you should use **spring MVC with hibernate**, because when your product become large,it create a problem in future due to many developers involvement.So, you should use framework , so that every developer follow the pattern and then your product remain stable.

```
But I am already follow hibernate pattern :)
```

I have no any knowledge of Spring MVC. When I search about spring MVC , I found it is a different thing than my requirement and also find Cross database context issue, if I use Spring MVC with hibernate.

Either should I used spring MVC or not. If yes, I have to learn then Spring MVC and 
I do not want to waste my time, if spring is not suitable for me.

That's why I am consulting that forum , to go for right direction.

Comment: Learning Spring is not wasting time. It's a de-facto standart for EE Java. And it definitely do not intersect with "hibernate pattern". Spring and Hibernate works excellent together.

Comment: @madhead please read again, I have edited that , why I said to waste my time :) be positive .

Comment: I am not negative. Spring is *very* widespread in Java world. Learning it is definitely not wasting time. And considering your question about Hibernate + Spring I say: they work like a charm together.

Comment: The book 'Spring in Action' is a great introduction to Spring as well as the concepts behind the framework. These concepts will prove useful for years to come.

Comment: @madhead I agree with you, but hibernate fulfill my requirement. I think hibernate is enough for my requirement. off course spring MVC is great. but time is limited and i have no time to learn spring. If it is really critical to learn Spring MVC then, off course, I will learn first . I am still confused, you can gave me a right direction positively , based upon my requirement. :)

Comment: @ShahidGhafoor Ok. How do you write Controllers in Hibernate? Web filters? How do you manage bean dependencies with Hibernate? Spring and Hibernate *do not intersect*. You'll write all your web logic and services with Spring, and you'll use Hibernate for data access layer. And that is MVC pattern!

Comment: @madhead now I am using Jquery JSP, Spring MVC and Hibernate in my projct :) ;) very interesting.

Comment: @ShahidGhafoor Good :) Enjoy it!

Answer (score 5):

Actually, Spring MVC does not interfere with any of the components you have chosen already. It just introduces a way to structure your frontend - backend interface in a standard way (MVC pattern).

I actually run the very same setup and is very happy with it. (Jquery, JSP, Spring MVC, Hibernate).

Other than structure, you will get easy return of invested time in Spring MVC when you want to do Ajax heavy things (as I assume you want in an ERP app). It's trivial to build AJAX/JSON stuff with jQuery and SpringMVC.

Comment: now same thing , (Jquery, JSP, Spring MVC, Hibernate), I am using . very interesting ;)

Answer (score 2):

Using Spring MVC will make your application structured. This will help in future maintenance.

Your code will look clean and you can separate your code into components and Spring will help you wire them together and you might decide to combine them in different ways, or wish to make it easy to swap out one component for another depending on different settings or environments. This would be great for multiple databases when used with hibernate.

Learning spring will not take much time if you have a good knowledge of Java EE.

Comment: agreed! Learning spring will not take much time if you have a good knowledge of j2ee. Now I have learned both and using both spring mvc and hibernate in our project